# Sublime Text RegEx pattern for text between HTML tags

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext

I'm using Sublime Text for some search&replace operations. This is an example I'm trying to replace

```
<blockquote><pre><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="1">code:</font><hr><font size="3">
    <h1>Stuff</h1>
    <p>More stuff and a <a href="#">link</a></p>
    <!-- and any HTML really -->
</font><hr></pre></blockquote>
```

to look like this

```
<blockquote>
    <h1>Stuff</h1>
    <p>More stuff and a <a href="#">link</a></p>
    <!-- and any HTML really -->
</blockquote>
```

The following pattern works as long the HTML inside the `blockquote` is single line only.

Search:

```
<blockquote><pre><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="1">code:</font><hr><font size="3">(.*?)</font><hr></pre></blockquote>
```

Replace:

```
<blockquote>$1</blockquote>
```

How can I make this work for multiple lines within the `blockquote`?

Edit: I came across `<tag>([\s\S]*?)</tag>` as well, but that includes the opening/closing tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up using `(?:<tag>)([\s\S]+?)(?:</tag>)`, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way to achieve the same

Comment: Thanks for this Regex! I checked out dozens of threads with the same question, but didn't find anything that matches the tags content between to tags plus new lines.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this: `<([/]*(font|pre|hr)+)\s*[^>]*>([code:])*`